# Web API Complex Data in Get

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am using Web APi, as I am new to this, I dont know much about it.
    I am trying to implement search, as of now I am starting with only text search, but later there may be huge search criteria. for one text that is easy, as web api works good with 
    primitive data types. Now I want to create a class of filter, say the pagenumber , the pagesize also all the search criteria, so I created a class. I have created a MVC application which is communicating with the web api, the web api returns Json data, then I de-serialize it to model. I am stuck with the complex object part, also as of now I am using a list to get the data, later that will be replaced by data base. Following is the code.

```
 public IEnumerable<Document> Get(PaggingDetails request)  //public async Task<IEnumerable<Note>> GetNotes() for Async (DB)
        {
            return _repository.GetAll(pagedetails.PageNumber, pagedetails.PageSize, pagedetails.PageFilter);
            //return await db.Notes.ToListAsync<Note>(); for async
        }

public string GetPage(int pagenumber,int pagesize,string pagefilter)
        {
            try
            {
                PaggingDetails PageDetails = new PaggingDetails();
                PageDetails.PageFilter     = pagefilter;
                PageDetails.PageSize       = pagesize;
                PageDetails.PageNumber     = pagenumber;
                return new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString
("http://.../api/Document/?pagedetails=" +
                                                                PageDetails);
                //new HttpClient().GetStringAsync("http://localhost:18545/api/Emails"); for async
                //also pass parameters 

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            return "";
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

By deafult, you cannot use a class as the type of parameter of a GET Web API action. You need to use individual parameters of single types.

If you want to use a class as parameter nothing stops you to use a POST action, in which you can include the data without any problem.

However you can force a complex parameter of a GET action to be read from the URI by decorating the comples attribute with [FromUri].

You can read this document to better understand Web API parameter binding:

[Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

> By default, Web API uses the following rules to bind parameters:
>
> - If the parameter is a “simple” type, Web API tries to get the value from the URI. Simple types include the .NET primitive types (int, bool, double, and so forth), plus TimeSpan, DateTime, Guid, decimal, and string, plus any type with a type converter that can convert from a string. (More about type converters later.)
> - For complex types, Web API tries to read the value from the message body, using a media-type formatter.

This is the standard way of working. If you use the `[FromUri]` attribute, the action selector won't be able to choose between different `Get` methods that receive different complex types. If you use a route with controller and action segments, you won't have that problem, becaus ethe actions selector will choose by action name, no matter what the aprameters are.

I don't like using the `[FromUri]` for this reason, and beacuse it's not the natural way to work with the GET action. But you can use it with the necessary precautions.